# Different colours for icons in the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I'am having different colours for the icons in the action bar of my app depending on the API level of the device. I'd like them to look the same across all the devices.

This is how it looks in API 23, which is how I want it to be in all the devices:

[image: This is how it looks in API 23, which is how I want it to be]

And this is how it looks in older versions:

[image]

I've got the following styles.xml:

**values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**v21/styles.xml**

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>
```

And this is the layout of the actionBar:

```
...
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
...
```

And this is part of my Manifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.martinez.mario.rutapp.base.RutappApplication"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" >
```

How can I make the arrow and the overflow icon to look white in all the devices?

Thanks.

Comment: I just realised that it is the same for my app. +1

Comment: It's weird that I have an app I wrote recently that has  white icons on < v21 devices. The only immediate difference I see is I didn't use a separate values file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably run into a bug in appcompat support library  23.2.0, update to 23.2.1 or enable the use of support vector drawables with:

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

Appcompat in 23.2.0 introduced the generation of vector support drawables if enabled, problem was that appcompat itself took advantage of this and used it too, but that required the vector drawables generation to be enabled. Its own usage of it was reverted again in 23.2.1 so as not to require this.

Comment: So the vector drawables are fixed now? I've been using 23.1.0 for the time being